# Empty NSMutableArray after adding elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Here's my project: https://github.com/a8b/musicManager/tree/master/musicManager

I have issue with *addSongToLibrary* method in *MusicCollection.m* - it doesn't add songs with *[library addSong:song]*

Comment: You should post the relevant code in your question and, if possible, describe your attempts to resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you initialize the array before accessing it?  Do you have something like `self.library = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` somewhere?

Comment: Yes, the problem was about allocation memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you commented out the following code

```
/*-(instancetype) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        library.songs = [NSMutableArray array];
        [library addSong:[Song new]];
    }
    return self;
}*/
```

so library is never instaniated, either you uncommented it , or in `viewDidLoad` you need to add `library.songs = [NSMutableArray array];` otherwise it will be nil.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify your code for clarity, it's doing this:

```
-(void) addSongToLibrary:(Song *)song {

  for (Song *song in library.songs) {
    NSLog(@"%@", song);
  }
  [library addSong:song];
 }
```

}

You are declaring a variable with the same name as a method parameter, so it is hiding the value passed in.

Comment: How can it help? [library.songs count] returns zero.